# why can't i reach any object in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch

i tried everything, for, forin forof and map loops, i cannot reach single objects wtih any of them

it seems that this is an array within array:

screenshot of browser console when code is executed

here is my code:

```
let lista = [];
const result = fetch(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.hnb.hr/tecajn-eur/v3"
)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => lista.push(data))
    .catch((error) => console.warn("E, nemere!!!!"));
console.log(lista);
console.log(typeof lista);
```

i tried to write lista[0] , data[0]

doesnt work

Comment: Put the code that should access/loop the list elements in the place where you currently do `lista.push(data)`. That's executed *when* the `data` will be available

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. If i write console.log(data[0]) in the bottom, i still don't get listed JUST the first element in array. i dont understand why not, even though in the original code console gives me still all the items. at least now i dont have that [0] index encompassing all other indexes

Comment: "*i dont understand why not*" - see the linked duplicate, or also https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572. "*even though in the original code console gives me still all the items*" - [no it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572). You'll realise what happens when you `console.log(items.length)`, or when you initialise `let lista = null`.